# How do I solve (TypeError) can't convert nil into String when trying to install rails on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install Ruby on Rails on my computer following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwo3Eda_ev0&index=2&list=PLVBFw0Pn9e9L7SOKtL8x4Av39drO5Oi-Q).

At the 7-minute mark, I am supposed to use the command:

```
gem install rails --version 3.0.0
```

and it looks like it is going well but then I get this error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError) can't convert nil into String

I have searched and searched and searched for solutions to this but all I keep finding is people having this problem when writing their programs not during installation and setup. What is going wrong?

Comment: Did you do `gems` or `gem`? I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be plural.

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong in one of the gems that's being installed. You might try to narrow down which gem it is. Or try a different, more recent version of Rails.

Comment: What version of Ruby do you have installed? Rails 3.0.0 is almost 4 years old now (Aug 2010) and was [written for 1.8.7](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.0/rails.gemspec#L10). Ruby has seen quite a few changes since then. It may be worthwhile finding a more recently published guide.

Comment: The guide is from last year I didn't think it would be that out of date. The ruby version is ruby 1.9.3p545

Comment: Rails 3.0.0 is like the lambo from the 50s while Rails today is like a lambo with flying wings

Comment: I went with a newer tutorial and it worked fine. Thanks Jonaskithan Lonowski